# How to implement fallback for SVG `<use href>` element for readers with normal vision?

Tags: html, css, svg, accessibility, fallback

I have an HTML5 document with fragment

```
<p class="special">Some text with an icon
<svg class=\"icon\">
<title>alternative text content for accessibility</title>
<use href="icons.svg#foo"></use>
</svg> in the middle of sentence.</p>
```

The `<title>` element is used to specify the alternative content for *accessibility* purposes. However, how should I markup the *alternative content for readers with normal vision* in case `<use href>` fails to load the required referenced resource to correctly render the image? It seems that the default action is to render element `<use>` fully transparent.

I would have expected to see `<use alt="...">` to define fallback for the referenced resource but that doesn't seem to exist. **How to specify fallback content for readers with normal vision (that is, not using accessibility tools that can access `<title>`)?**

I'm trying to use inline CSS to allow referenced graphics to use `style="fill:currentColor"` to inherit correct color from the context (the color of which is defined with CSS using selector `p.special`). I know that if I used HTML5 `<img>` element I could just use the attribute `alt`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without using some JS trickery that would cause unnecessary weight. There are quite a few ways to fall back if the browser doesn't support SVG `<use>` at all, but if it is supported and the reference does not exist I am pretty sure it is designed to fail silently. As I said I think the option would be load the file with JS, check for the relevant ID and then if it does not exist add some filler text. I would imagine this would be less robust so perhaps I would check this at build time with a custom script? Do you expect this to fail often?

Comment: I don't expect this to fail often but I've been previously bitten with Firefox failing to load external SVG filters applied with `filter: url(...)` which results in fully transparent element without fallback. I'm trying to figure out an usable fallback (e.g. render some unicode emoji instead of real icon if loading external SVG fails). Icon fonts have similar problems where icon fonts often use private use area and if the font loading fails, any random iconography from some locally installed font private use area will be rendered instead.